# Insufficient privilege: 7 ОШИБКА: нужно быть владельцем отношения XXX

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь удалить только что созданный тригер и процедуру в Postgresql и выдает такую ошибку.

Пробовал следовать манам и сделать текущего пользователя владельцем базы, с которой работаю. Хотя он и так, вроде, был владельцем.  [тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) написано как. Так же питался дать все права как сказано [тут](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

SQL для удаления выглядит так:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_params ON XXX CASCADE;
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А текущий пользователь является владельцем таблицы XXX, как на то намекает сообщение об ошибке? (`\dt XXX` в psql)

Comment: Да, я же написал, что сделал его владельцем. Хотя, с другой стороны, я не знаю, как проверить, действительно ли он владелец.

Comment: Да, посмотрел. Убедился. Текущий пользователь и есть владелец.

Comment: А я написал, как проверить: `\dt XXX` в psql. Еще как вариант можно попробовать сказать `drop trigger ... restrict` и посмотреть, нет ли внезапно каких-то зависимостей. И да, если проблема воспроизводится, то хорошо бы конечно увидеть скрипт.

Comment: А, все, проблема была в том, что сначала нужно было удалить процедуру, которую вызывал тригер. Странно, что до этого была подобная ошибка и решилась обратной последовательностью удалений. Сначала тригер, потом процедуру. Сейчас вот наоборот. Надо бы разобраться, с чем связано отличие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важна последовательность удаления. Помогло сначала удалить процедуру, а потом триггер.